# How does this apposition work?

Tags: classical-latin

I'm reading [Wheelock's Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelock%27s_Latin) and I stumbled across this passage at page **90**:

> Nōn amo tē, Sabidī, nec possum dīcere quārē.
> Hoc tantum possum dīcere: nōn amo tē.

Why is the name **Sabidius** used with the genitive singular **Sabidī** in the apposition?
Since **Sabidius** is in apposition with **te** shouldn't it appear as **Sabidium** because **te** is the direct object of the verb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Sabidi* is not the genitive, but the vocative, used to address someone. It is not an apposition, but stands alone, not in agreement with *te* or anything else (this is indicated by the commata in modern usage).

Thus, the sentence translates: “I do not love you, Sabidius, …”

The vocative is always identical to the nominative, except:

- 2nd declension nouns/names in *-us*: vocative singular in *-e* (for example *Quintus* → *Quinte*)
- 2nd declension nouns/names in *-ius*: vocative singular in *-ī* (for example *Iulius* → *Iuli*)
- *meus* → *mī*
- *deus* → *deus* (not attested classically, but obviously became important later on)

So you say *Marce Tulli, quid agis?* (not nominative!), or: *Liquere hoc tibi, Lucili, scio* (not dative), etc.

Needless to say, this is only possible in the second person. Talking about a third party, the name would indeed have to be in agreement; however, the combination of a demonstrative adjective and a name is very rare. (It can sometimes be seen with *ille*, e.g. *fingamus Catilinam illum in nostras oras forte inferri* etc., the meaning is “the infamous Catilina.”)